# How to add my container's hostname to /etc/hosts?

Tags: docker, hosts

In order to support some old software solutions, I need to bind my container's `hostname` to `127.0.0.1`, leaving me with something like this:

```
$ hostname
4e84a7ae5f92
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       localhost 4e84a7ae5f92
```

Best case scenario would be to do in the Dockerfile, but since `docker build` builds an image (and not a container), it doesn't seem realistic.
Also if I try to do it with `sed` in the running container, I end up with an error:

```
$ sed -i '/^127\.0\.0\.1.*/ s/$/ '$(hostname)'/' /etc/hosts
sed: cannot rename /etc/sedC5PkA2: Device or resource busy
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docker `run` command has an option named `--hostname=""` which takes care of your `/etc/hostname` file.

The host-to-ip mapping in the `/etc/hosts` file can be managed with the option `--add-host=[]` then.

Comment: Indeed, but how do I provide it with the container id that I'm about to run (and hence wich doesn't exist already) ?

Comment: Just give it a meaningful name and don't use the container ids at all.

Comment: Ok and then use the `--add-host` option with the defined hostname I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to add the container name to `/etc/hosts` is using the flag `--add-host`. In your case, suppose that you want to create and start a new container named `<container-name>` using the image `<image-name>` in detached mode:

```
docker run --name <container-name> --add-host <container-name>:127.0.0.1 -d <image-name>`
```

This will create the following `/etc/hosts` (please note the last line):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       4e84a7ae5f92
```

It has been tested using Docker 1.12.0-rc2.